# Android XML Attrs Not working with Custom Library

Tags: android, xml, xml-namespaces, android-library

I'm currently building a library project and I'm having some issue with XML properties. In the library module I created the `declare-styleable in attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="betterTextViewAttrs">
    <attr name="typefaceAsset" format="string"/>
    <attr name="scaleWithinBounds" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And I want to reference the attrs in the project's sample layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:bettertv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.virtualprodigy.bettertextviewsample.MainActivity">

<com.virtualprodigy.bettertextview.BetterTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    bettertv:typefaceAsset="dancing _script.ttf"
    bettertv:scaleWithinBounds="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main" />
```

But for some reason the `xmlns:bettertv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` isn't working. and I get the following error when I compile.

`Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'typefaceAsset' in package 'com.virtualprodigy.bettertextviewsample'`

The full source can be found here on GitHub. Any help is appreciated.

[BetterTextView GitHub Project](https://github.com/virtualprodigy/BetterTextView/tree/bug-fix/xmlNameSpace_DialogForTTFInDemo)

Answer (score 0):

After staring down my project I realized the issue. Even though Android Studio creates a library project for you through the GUI it does not automatically add the `compile project(':bettertextview')` in the `build.gradle` file.  Updating this completely resolved the issue.